# Insert into one table the data of another table

Tags: php, mysql

This query is supposed to copy the members table row into the membersd table and then delete the row from the members table. There is more to it, of course, but the INSERT query is the one that doesn't work. Is this correct syntax for the first query? I'm only a beginner but it looks like it's missing something simple.

```
  $qry="INSERT INTO ".$prefix."membersd (SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."members WHERE Id=".$_SESSION[userid].")";
  mysql_query($qry);

  mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$prefix."members WHERE Id = ".$_SESSION[userid]);
```

Comment: Is *membersd* & *members* table structure same?

Comment: actually no the fields that exist in membersd do also exist in members table but the members table has quite a few more fields.
they could be the same though if they needed to be for the query to work

Comment: what's the structure of members and membersd? Whats the error that you are getting? why not use prepared statement instead?

Comment: This will work if column name are same in both tables

Comment: The best way to work this stuff out is to Perform a var_dump of $qry ie var_dump($qry). Copy it and paste it into something like the SQL via phpmyadmin and check the result...

Comment: Check Whether `$_SESSION[userid]` value coming or not. All Look Well From Here

Comment: And I am thinking you r not getting $_SESSION value or didn't start session yet

Comment: $_SESSION[userid] value is coming because the second query to "delete from" members does happen.

Comment: Most important. Mysql_* is deprecated and closed in php7 use prepared statement this will prevent code from SQL attack

Comment: I think I understand what's wrong now. I think Nana is correct the structure of members is not the same as membersd anymore, that needs to be correct. So question answered, the syntax should work as long as it's prepared correctly, and as per devpro I should probably work it out, instead of using *
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing second argument of mysql query which is connection object $con or something

> mysql_query( $sql, $con );

and you might have defined it like this

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$con    = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: Not Necessary To include column name when having same structure.

Comment: *yes exactly the same – Brian Zens* Commented. So, That's The Case.